# Could not obtain native oracle connection

Tags: java, oracle, tomcat, geotools

Asked in gis.stackexchange: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23412/could-not-obtain-native-oracle-connection

Anyone knows the the cause and how to resolve the "Could not obtain native oracle connection" error?

I'm using GeoTools 2.7.4, a oracle 11g DB, ojdbc14.jar, and a simple java code on a Tomcat 6 like this:

```
Map map = new HashMap();
map.put( "dbtype", "oracle");
map.put( "jndiReferenceName", "java:comp/env/jdbc/GisDS");

OracleNGJNDIDataStoreFactory factory = new OracleNGJNDIDataStoreFactory();
log.info("Can process? "+ factory.canProcess(map));
store = factory.createDataStore(map);

SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = store.getFeatureSource(viewName);
log.info(featureSource.getFeatures().getBounds().toString());
```

And my context.xml:

```
<Resource name="jdbc/GisDS" auth="Container" type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
    driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"
    accessToUnderlyingConnectionAllowed="true" 
    username="***" password="***"
    url="***"
    maxActive="25" maxIdle="8" maxWait="10000" 
    removeAbandoned="true" removeAbandonedTimeout="60" logAbandoned="true" 
    poolPreparedStatements="true" maxOpenPreparedStatements="100"
    validationQuery="SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL"/>
```

And I always get the "Could not obtain native oracle connection" error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:485)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureStore.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureStore.java:179)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureSource.getBounds(ContentFeatureSource.java:370)
        at org.geotools.data.store.ContentFeatureCollection.getBounds(ContentFeatureCollection.java:274)
        at ***.GisServlet.doGet(GisServlet.java:82)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:617)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error occured calculating bounds
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1137)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCFeatureSource.getBoundsInternal(JDBCFeatureSource.java:478)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Could not obtain native oracle connection for class org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper
        at org.geotools.data.oracle.OracleDialect.unwrapConnection(OracleDialect.java:490)
        at org.geotools.data.oracle.OracleDialect.readGeometry(OracleDialect.java:434)
        at org.geotools.data.oracle.OracleDialect.readGeometry(OracleDialect.java:424)
        at org.geotools.data.oracle.OracleDialect.decodeGeometryEnvelope(OracleDialect.java:371)
        at org.geotools.jdbc.JDBCDataStore.getBounds(JDBCDataStore.java:1123)
        ... 20 more
```

I've tried to connect to a 10g DB, I've tried using the ojdbc6, and I always end with the same result.

The strange thing is, if I replace the `getBounds()` with `size()` it works.

Comment: Not familiar with Geotools, but is there any reason you can't use the thin driver?

Comment: I use the thin driver (At least I think I do). The context.xml above is missing the url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@***".

Comment: did you get anywhere with this? I'm seeing the same problem using GeoServer to connect to an Oracle data store. It lists available tables / views no problem but then dies when I try to calculate the layer's bounds

Comment: @tomfumb Nop, I didn't get anywhere... I've filled an issue in the geotools jira (http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOT-4106) but with no good response either. In the meanwhile I'm creating the connection in the code (http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/jdbc/oracle.html). If you create the connection that way it works... Not my expected solution but is better than nothing.

Comment: The Oracle JDBC package names reference the Java version they are for not the driver version. Get the latest driver for the Oracle Database and Java version you are using.